# AUCTeX auto parse class file in same directory as TeX file

Tags: latex, auctex

I have a class file `hmcpset.cls` which defines some macros and environments.

If I have it in the same directory as a TeX file, which uses `\documentclass{hmcpset}`, I would like AUCTeX to parse the class file, so it can complete the macros and environments defined in it.

I know AUCTeX can do this, because, with `(setq TeX-auto-save t)` opening `hmcpset.cls` and saving it causes the file to be parsed and from then on, I can complete things defined in it, even in the TeX file.

Comment: Open the class file and force parsing with C-c C-n, then do the same in your document file.

Comment: I would like to make this automatic.

Comment: It is if you set TeX-auto-save to t. You just have to edit the file to trigger parsing

Comment: I mean, I would like this to happen even if I don't edit the class file and only edit the TeX file.

Comment: You have at least to visit the file somehow in order for the parsing to happen.